# Regular expression for email to allow only two domain

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have to create a regular expression for email id like this

xyz@yahoo.com and
xyz@gmail.com

I need to allow only yahoo and gmail as the domain not any other domain. I have used this expression \w+([-+.]\w+)*@yahoo.com . It is working fine for yahoo. but I want to include gmail also. How can I modify it to except gmail also?

I am using ASP.NET 2.0

Comment: Why not just check the substring from the @

Comment: @Tom Gullen, Because regular expressions are *always* the right choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
yahoo\.com
```

with:

```
(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com)
```

or:

```
((yahoo|gmail)\.com)
```

---

Answer (score 2):

To put an alternative in you just need to do `(yahoo\.com|gmail\.com)` and that should match either one.

Comment: `.` matches any character. `yahooTcom` would pass your test.

Comment: True. I was just basing it on copy paste from the original, adding the alternatives. Clearly was too early for my brian to be fully engaged. :) I should also add that in the original regex I suspect there are a lot of things that aren't properly covered but there so often are with e-mail regexes...

Answer (score 1):

+([-+.]\w+)*@(?:yahoo|gmail).com

Answer (score 0):

1. read on [this article on email validation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) since your regex isn't perfect, and if false positives/negatives are a concern
2. first check if your email string contains "@yahoo" or "@gmail"
3. use information from 1. to check if that string is a valid email

**Update**: a ready made email validator can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx); since it's from MSDN, it should be correct